# BitShif in Long data type

Tags: c#

I have the following code that performs bit shift left and stores it in a long data type.
You can also run the the C# [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WbV0AC) to test this out.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    long s;
    s = (1 << 29);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    s = (1 << 30);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    s = (1 << 31);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    s = (1 << 32);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    s = (1 << 33);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
  }
}
```

The output is

```
536870912
1073741824
-2147483648
1
2
```

Why starting at 31st bit, the value is no longer valid? I thought long can hold up quite a large number? I also test this out at the [online bit shift calculator](https://bit-calculator.com/bit-shift-calculator) and (1 << 31) gives me 4294967296 and not -2147483648.

Comment: You're shifting and `int`.  Try defining `long x = 1;` and then do the shifting on that `s = (x << 31)`.  Or you can do `s = (1L << 31)` to make sure you're shifting a `long`.

Comment: Thaks Juharr, do you mind copy this to the answer and I can accept it?